# Database query android sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I am stuck with one scenario in which I need to do complex query to get cursor. Don't know It is possible or not. Scenario is : 
There are three tables in database.

```
 Table         Columns  
Table-1    _id, name, number, ....  
Table-2    _id, table1_id, col1, col2, ....  
Table-3    _id, table2_id, col1, col2, ....
```

In these tables, when any record is inserted in table 2, corresponding table1 id is inserted in that record. Same for table2 id is inserted with table 3 record.

I want cursor for CursorAdapter to display list view of Table-3 data.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(TABLE_3_NAME, null, null, null, null);
```

Now need to add selection and selection args of Table-1 in this query.
Is it possible in Android?

Comment: do you want to display data of table 3 in listview and that from get data from table 1 when select particular data from listview

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw query to fetch from various tables. One example would be as below.

```
 Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table-1, Table-3 " +
                         "WHERE Table1.id = <Whatever selection args you want> " +
                         "GROUP BY Table1.id", null);
```

This is just an example. You will have to change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a SQL selection query (i.e. normal way) and you can execute using [**rawQuery()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method.

For example:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```